# Selecting records with IF in where Clause?

Tags: mysql, select

I need to extract some data from table

For example:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| Code        | Progress   |   QTY       | Faulty     |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+  
| A           | 10         |      100    |    0       |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| B           | 1          |      10     |    0       |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| C           | 4          |      0      |    1       |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| D           | 7          |      100    |    0       |                 
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+


SELECT Code, Progress, QTY, Faulty 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Progress <> 7 AND Progress = 4 AND QTY > 0
```

How to select all records that have 
- Progress <> 7 
- and Progress 4 but only when QTY of row with progress for is greater than 0 
- and value of Faulty is 1?

Comment: Please share your current query. You don't need `IF` I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give it a try

```
SELECT 
Code, 
Progress, 
QTY, 
Faulty 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Progress NOT IN(4,7)
      OR (Progress = 4 AND QTY > 0 AND Faulty = 1)
```

---

**Explanation:**

Condition like `Progress <> 7` will bring records having `Progress = 4`. That particular record might not have `QTY > 0 AND Faulty = 1`.

That's why use `Progress NOT IN (4,7)` as the first condition.

Now you need to worry about your second case which is pretty straight like you mentioned.

`(Progress = 4 AND QTY > 0 AND Faulty = 1)`

Records having `Progress = 4 having QTY >0 and Faulty = 1` will be brought into the final result set.

Comment: This works but I need to hide records which have progress = 4 and qty = 0.

The rules is: show all records with progress different than 7 and hide records which have progress 4 and qty =0

Comment: Records having `progress = 4 and QTY = 0` aren't supposed to appear in the result set. Please share the query you tried.

Comment: Sorry, works now. Problem with my IDE... Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where Progress<>7 
and Progress in (select Progress from table t where QTY>0 and Faulty =1)
```